# Как остановить нить с помощью interrupt

Tags: java

Разбираюсь с нитями.
На сколько я понял, interrupt, по сути, не останавливает нить. Это всего лишь флаг, который показывает, что мы хотим ее остановить. А уж как мы ее остановим, это уже наши проблемы. 
В каком-то смысле, это можно представить себе, как if else. Да, ветка else есть, в тоже время, что в ней будет, мы должны указать сами. Или может быть try catch — что будет, если возникнет исключение, мы должны указать сами.
Таким образом, если у нас, допустим, есть код:

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {      
        TestThread testThread = new TestThread();
        testThread.start();
        testThread.interrupt();
    }
    public static class TestThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!this.isInterrupted()) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

то testThread.interrupt() не останавливает нить, а всего лишь дает нам "инструмент", условие, намерение, флаг, а останавливаем ее мы сами в методе run() класса нити. Тогда зачем вообще эти interrupt, interrupted, isInterrupted нужны? Если мы все делаем сами. Мы могли создать и назвать boolean как угодно.

Плюс, я так понимаю, есть нюанс с методом Thread.sleep, который проверяет флаг. И благодаря этом, работает вот такое прерывание:

```
public class Solution {
    public static volatile int numSeconds = 4;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        RacingClock clock = new RacingClock();
        Thread.sleep(3500);
        clock.interrupt();
    }
    public static class RacingClock extends Thread {
        public RacingClock() {
            start();
        }
        public void run() {           
            for (; numSeconds > 0; numSeconds--) {
                System.out.print(numSeconds + " ");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Прервано!");
                    return;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Марш!");
        }
    }
}
```

то есть, насколько я понимаю из-за Thread.sleep(3500) в main в run класса нити мы ловим исключение и проходим по catch.
Ну и нюанс, что interrupted после проверки очищает флаг (устанавливает false), поэтому, в случае проверки, флаг необходимо будет восстановить.
Правильно ли я рассуждаю?

Comment: Ваши рассуждеия верны. После проверки 
и *после обработки InterruptedException* надо обязательно снова взводить этот флаг, иначе есть большой риск "проглотить" прерывание

Answer (score 0):

Метод `interrupt()` не устанавливает никаких флагов для остановки потока, а берет и прерывает поток путем возбуждения исключения `InterruptedException`, и т.к. исключения из потоков не выбрасываются выше, то исключение заставляет поток прервать свою работу до завершения блока метода `run()`, одновременно с этим для потока устанавливается флаг прерванного потока, и метод `isInterrupted()` возвращает нам `true`.

`Thread.sleep()` используется в блоке `try-catch` потому что метод `sleep()` выбрасывает исключение `InterruptedException`, для того, чтобы при выходе из блокировки (а поток блокируется на время сна) проверить, а жив ли еще поток.

Как реализован метод `isInterrupted()` внутри, я не скажу, он нативный, меня это не интересовало.

Comment: Нет влага прерывания? М?https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

Comment: Флаг - как сигнал для прерывания и флаг прерванного потока. Есть разница? М? @Tsyklop

Comment: @dmtr исключение не возбуждается, оно выбрасывается методами, которые проверяют `Thread.currentThread().interrupted()`. Поток зависший в `while(true);` в java (по крайней мере hotspot и openjdk) никак не прибить, не завершая всю jvm